# windows 10/8.1/7 not booting after installing new RAM

Tags: windows, boot, memory, motherboard

My motherboard is Gigabyte GA-H55M-USB3 (Rev 1). I have 4 slots for RAM. I had 2x2 GB DDR3 RAM 667 MHz(9-9-9-24). With this Windows was booting fine. Now, I have installed 1x8 gb DDR3 RAM 1600 Mhz(10-10-10-27). Now, windows is not booting. I have tried with different slots but no success. Before buying I checked hardware compatibility which was fine but now Windows is not working. Please help.

Comment: Does the memory show up in the firmware.  Have you ran memtestx86 yet? Have you updated the firmware to hr current version l?  Does safe mode work?  Update our question not submit comments

Comment: The short summary to harry's answer, you can't have a stick larger than 4 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data in your post, you have evidently bought the wrong RAM for your
motherboard.

The [specification for GA-H55M-USB3](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H55M-USB3-rev-20#sp) says this about memory :

> - 4 x 1.5V DDR3 DIMM sockets supporting up to 16 GB of system memory (Note 1)
> - Dual channel memory architecture
> - Support for DDR3 2200+/1800/1600/1333/1066/800 MHz memory modules
> - Support for non-ECC memory modules
> - Support for Extreme Memory Profile (XMP) memory modules
> - To reach DDR3 2200 MHz and above, you are required to use with Intel Core i7/Core i5 CPU without HD Graphics and install a discrete
>     graphics card. When using Intel Core i5/Core i3/ Pentium CPU with HD
>     Graphics, the maximum memory speed supported is 1666 MHz
> - Go to GIGABYTE's website for the latest memory support list.

The above restrictions are quite draconian, and we need to know your CPU.

The excellent memory-upgrade site of Crucial only [suggests](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Giga-Byte/ga-h55m-usb3) upgrades
having 2GB or 4GB. No 8 GB ones are recommended.

Taken together with the fact that your motherboard is specified by Giga-Byte
as having 4 DIMMs but can only reach up to 16 GB,
the conclusion is that it does not support 8 GB DIMMs.

I would suggest to return the RAM you bought and ask for reimbursement.

For upgrades, it is best to download and run the [Crucial System Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/).
That tool is extremely precise, and will suggest upgrades and slots.
When placing the RAM, it is very important to follow the guidelines
as specified in the [motherboard manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-h57m(h55m)-usb3_v2.0_e.pdf), and especially the following:

> When  enabling  Dual  Channel  mode  with  two  or  four  memory 
>   modules,  it  is  recommended  that  memory  of  the  same  capacity, 
>   brand,  speed,  and  chips  be  used  for  optimum  performance.  When
>   enabling Dual Channel mode with two memory modules, be sure to install
>   them in the DDR3_1 and  DDR3_3 sockets.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I buy 2x4 gb ddr3 ram (whatever frequency) with addition to  my current 2x2 gb ram then will things run fine?

Comment: my cpu is i3 530

Comment: Yes - the best you can achieve is 4 x 4GB = 16GB. But use the Crucial tool - RAM is too complex a subject for me to give a definitive answer (and their prices are very competitive and they guarantee the scanner's result).